# Getting nans for gradient

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to create a search relevance model where I take the dot product between query vector and resulting documents. I add a positional bias term on top to take into account the fact that position 1 is more likely to be clicked on. The final (unnormalised) log likelihood calculation is as follows:

```py
        query = self.query_model(query_input_ids, query_attention_mask)
        docs = self.doc_model(doc_input_ids, doc_attention_mask)
        positional_bias = self.position_model()
        
        if optimizer_idx is not None:
            if optimizer_idx == 0:
                docs = docs.detach()
                positional_bias = positional_bias.clone().detach()
            elif optimizer_idx == 1:
                query = query.detach()
                positional_bias = positional_bias.clone().detach()
            else:
                query = query.detach()
                docs = docs.detach()
                
        similarity = (docs @ query.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze()

        click_log_lik = (similarity + positional_bias)\
                .reshape(doc_mask.shape)\
                .masked_fill_((1 - doc_mask).bool(), float("-inf"))
```

The query and doc model is simply a distilbert model with a projection layer on top of CLS token. The models can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/g21g9MG3

When inspecting the first gradient descent step, it has `nan`s, but only for the query model and not the doc model. **My hypothesis** is that normalizing the return values for doc and query models (`return F.normalize(out, dim=-1)`) is somehow playing up with the gradients.

Does anyone know <s>1. If my hypothesis is true</s> and more importantly 2. **How can I rectify nan gradients?**.

### Additional Info:

- None of the losses are inf or nan.
- query is BS x 768
- docs is BS x DOC_RESULTS x 768
- positional_bias is DOC_RESULTS
- DOC_RESULTS is 10 in my case.
- The `masked_fill` in the last line is because occasionally I have less than 10 data points for a query.

### Update 1

The following changes made no difference to nans:

- Changing `masked_fill` from `-inf` to `1e5`.
- Changing the projection from `F.normalize(out, dim=-1)` to `out / 100`.
- Removed positional bias altogether with again no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps anyone, and you come across this while using Transformers this is what I did:

So in the end the bug was due to the fact that I was masking away nan's. Since I had some documents with zero length, the output of the transformer was nan. I was hoping that `masked_fill` would fix this problem, but it doesn't. The solution in my case was to only put non-zero length sequences through transformers, and then append with zeros to fill the batch size.